# How much experience should I put in my CV for selenium

Tags: selenium

I have not worked in Selenium but I know selenium. So, just want to know that how should I put this in my CV so that companies can hire me on basis of Selenium.

Comment: This isn't the right forum for this question.  I'd suggest careers, or something similar.

Comment: How can you know Selenium if you have not worked in Selenium? Have you done any private project with it?

Comment: Yes I have done private project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a selenium project and post it into Github, then mention it in your CV. You project should use many basic selenium statements. In my opinion, your project should cover 36 lessons of this [course](https://www.udemy.com/selenium-webdriver-with-java-testng-and-log4j/?siteID=0Is1SEV6Ap4-_KX26LOe90cepxbUN3SzQQ&LSNPUBID=0Is1SEV6Ap4) (from lesson 50 to lesson 85). I hope that this will help.